# cordova-plugin-fcm ERROR : invalid api key

Tags: cordova, firebase, push-notification, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm). I have followed the installation instruction:

1. install plugin
2. add the `google-services.json` to my root folder

I wanted to test it through their [testing server](https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/), but I get the error:

```
ERROR: invalid api key
```

The key I inserted was the one from the file `google-service.json` in the entry:

```
"api_key": [{"current_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]
```

How can I do the testing properly?

Comment: Is it the same Server Key seen in your Firebase Console?

Comment: it is not the same as the server key. i changed it to now to server key and it is working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using FCM, you should always make use of the Server Key seen in the Cloud Messaging Tab in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).