# Authentication error while sending notification using FCM gem RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM gem in rails

```
 fcm = FCM.new(Rails.application.config.api_key)
    registration_ids= ["<got from android app>"] # an array of one or more client registration tokens
    options = {data: {score: "123"}, collapse_key: "updated_score"}
    response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options) 
    puts "response: #{response}"
```

I am getting error: "There was an error authenticating the sender account"

Response is:

> {"body":"\u003cHTML\u003e\n\u003cHEAD\u003e\n\u003cTITLE\u003eUnauthorized\u003c/TITLE\u003e\n\u003c/HEAD\u003e\n\u003cBODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\"\u003e\n\u003cH1\u003eUnauthorized\u003c/H1\u003e\n\u003cH2\u003eError 401\u003c/H2\u003e\n\u003c/BODY\u003e\n\u003c/HTML\u003e\n","headers":{"content-type":["text/html; charset=UTF-8"],"date":["Thu, 16 Mar 2017 14:04:27 GMT"],"expires":["Thu, 16 Mar 2017 14:04:27 GMT"],"cache-control":["private, max-age=0"],"x-content-type-options":["nosniff"],"x-frame-options":["SAMEORIGIN"],"x-xss-protection":["1; mode=block"],"server":["GSE"],"alt-svc":["quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"37,36,35\""],"accept-ranges":["none"],"vary":["Accept-Encoding"],"connection":["close"]},"status_code":401,"response":"There was an error authenticating the sender account."}

On searching, I found that I need to whitelist server.
I am using heroku server. Where I can whitelist it? Please help

Comment: For FCM, *Unauthorized* error usually means that you're using a wrong value for the Server Key (aka API Key).

Comment: @AL. HI, I got this API from google service json file which was doenloaded from firebase console
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "*******"
        }
      ],

Am i referring to correct api key?

Comment: Hi dips. When using FCM, you should use the Server Key visible in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com). See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39841457/4625829).

Comment: @AL. Hey,Thanks you were very correct, issue was the wrong key,as i was using api key, instead of server key.
Could you please add this as an answer?

Comment: Hi dips. Just added it in. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using FCM, you should always make use of the Server Key seen in the *Cloud Messaging* Tab in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).